# How do I change current batc values in the table of Postgresql in one time

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I change all current values of some column in the table of Postgresql in one time?

For example, I have the table like this

From

```
ID  | Name | Amount | 
 ---------------------
1   | Josh | 21234  | 
2   | Sue  | 22345  | 
3   | Clark| 23454  | 
:   |   :  |   :    | 
:   |   :  |   :    | 
100 | Jake|  24545  |
```

To

```
ID  | Name | Amount | 
 ---------------------
1   | Josh | 51234  | 
2   | Sue  | 52345  | 
3   | Clark| 523454 | 
:   |   :  |   :    | 
:   |   :  |   :    | 
100 | Jake | 54545  |
```

I think "ALTER SEQUENCE" may not work.

Answer (score 1):

step 1.        Create a dummy table with ID and AMOUNT

step 2.        Join this to main table and update

```
UPDATE main_table AS m 
SET m.amount = d.amount
FROM dummy_table AS d
WHERE m.ID = d.ID
```